# Hive Join Query throws Error

Tags: sql, hive

If a user_id  has multiple records then keep the latest record as per event_timestamp .

My HIVE query :

```
SELECT 
 a.user_id,
 unix_timestamp(event_timestamp,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM') as  converted_event_timestamp,
 a.user_name,
 a.user_location
 FROM 
 sports_views a
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT user_id,MAX(unix_timestamp(event_timestamp,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM')) as max_event_timestamp FROM sports_views GROUP BY user_id )b
 ON( a.user_id =b.user_id AND a.converted_event_timestamp =b.max_event_timestamp)
 LIMIT 10;
```

When I try to run this hive query I get the below error

```
SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 8:43 Invalid column reference 'converted_event_timestamp'
```

Can Someone tell me what went wrong on this hive query and how do I fix this ?

Comment: Apparently there is no `converted_event_timestamp` in `sports_views `. It looks like you meant to use `unix_timestamp(a.event_timestamp,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not support join by alias. Use `unix_timestamp(event_timestamp,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM')` in join condition instead or calculate it in a subquery.

```
ON( a.user_id =b.user_id AND unix_timestamp(a.event_timestamp,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM')=b.max_event_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see where you have named a.converted_event_timestamp  in your query. You can't use it in the join because that is likely evaluated before the conversions in the select. Join to this instead

`unix_timestamp(a.event_timestamp,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM')`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT a.user_id,a.user_name, a.user_location from

(SELECT
 a.user_id,
 unix_timestamp(event_timestamp,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM') as  converted_event_timestamp,
 a.user_name,
 a.user_location
 FROM 
 sports_views ) a
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT user_id,MAX(unix_timestamp(event_timestamp,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM')) as max_event_timestamp FROM sports_views GROUP BY user_id )b
 ON( a.user_id =b.user_id AND a.converted_event_timestamp =b.max_event_timestamp)
 LIMIT 10;

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.userid, a.unix_timestamp(event_timestamp,'yyyy/MM/dd hh:MM') as min 
    from sports_views a 
    inner join (select userid, first_value(1) over(order by time desc) as max 
        from(select userid,unix_timestamp(event_timestamp,'yyyy/MM/dd hh:MM') as time 
        from sports_views)sv )e) 
where a.min=max
```